# Blender: How to "meshify" an object I made from Bezier curves

Tags: blender

I made a star shape using Bezier curves, and extruded it (see pic below):

[image]

What I want to do is give it a rounder look - not just around the edges by using beveling. I want it to kind of look like this (well, that shape anyway):

[image]

How would I go about doing this? Please keep in mind that I am extremely new to Blender.

I thought that I could somehow turn this star into those default shapes that have tonnes of squares which I could pull out, and apply a mirror to it so that the same thing happens on both sides. I really don't know how to do it, and would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a programming question, but try ALT+C combination, it should give you an option to convert it to mesh.

Comment: @VladimirMitrovic ALT+C just fills the curve, I tried it again to make sure. Thanks though.

Comment: @VladimirMitrovic I have really bad luck with questions here, I keep asking ones which seem to be off topic. Do you know which stackexchange would be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: You should read the [faq](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting. There is no SE site focusing 3d modeling. You should try [Blenderartists.org](http://blenderartists.org/) for blender related question.

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blender

Comment: ALT+C must be done in object mode (exit edit mode with TAB). Then select Mesh from ...

Comment: @iamcreasy do not bother searching because the old graphic section of SE has been closed long ago, there are no dedicated places this kind of questions on SE.

Comment: Nobody mentioned http://blender.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I don't see how this would be off-topic if it's for a game.  "Game Development" encompasses a broad range of subjects and doesn't imply programming only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ALT+C` will help you to convert a path to a mesh, then select a loop like in figure

[image]

`E` for extruding and right after press `S` to scale and move the cursor to the center of the star.

Now you get how to extrude the shape to the center, to give a vertical extrusion just press `E` and right after `G` to grab and then the axis where you want to move the selection like `Z`.

To create the final point for closing the center of the star just press `E` again with the final edge loop selected and press `ALT+M` to collapse the selection to the center of the shape.

With this you can achieve what you want to do.

---

this star is simply generated through a script:

- go in the User Preferences panel
- Addons > Add Mesh
- Enable `Extra Objects`
- just exit or *Save as default* as you wish
- `SHIFT+A` in the 3D viewport
- Mesh > Extra Objects > Basic Objects > Star

Comment: Hmm, my star shape looks different from yours. Notice how my selected loop is based on Bezier curves and is in the middle of the star shape? How did you make your star? Really looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @capcom i have added the appropriate details

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, wanting to convert NURBS curve-surfaces (curves with taper & bevel) into MESHes. I couldn't find a direct "convert to Mesh" command.

Select the objects to be converted.
Export the selected objects to STL format.
   File >> Export >> Stl (.stl)
Import the STL version back into blender (where it shows up as a mesh).
   File >> Import >> Stl (.stl)

Answer (score 0):

In **Object Mode**, with your object selected, type **Alt+C** and a menu **"Convert to"** will show, in the menu chose: **"Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text"**.